# Number of ways to delete a binary tree if only leaves can be deleted

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

I am solving an algorithm [question](https://binarysearch.com/problems/Ways-to-Remove-Leaves-of-a-Tree):

> You are given a binary tree `root`. In one operation you can delete one leaf node in the tree. Return the number of different ways there are to delete the whole tree. So, if the tree is:

```
    1
  /  \
 2     3
     /
    4
```

The expected answer is `3`: `[2, 4, 3, 1]`,`[4, 2, 3, 1]` and `[4, 3, 2, 1]`.

I have been thinking hard, but I don't know how to formulate the recursive function.  Thinking along the lines of the [Climbing Stairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/) problem in which we count "distinct ways can you climb to the top", I think I have to use DP, but I am unable to formulate the recursive relation.

If you could provide some hints/guidance, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Edit:
Given the following tree:

```
    1
  /  \
 2     3
     /   \
    4     5
```

There are 2 ways in which we could delete the children of `3` (`4`, `5`); but how to use this info to determine the number of ways for root node `1`?  (The expected answer is `8`).

Comment: Take a root with two children, if you were given the number of ways each child tree can be deleted together with their sizes, can you compute the number of ways the whole tree can be deleted? If so, then you only need to know that a leaf subtree can be deleted in exactly one way and the recursion is then trivial.

Comment: "if you were given the number of ways each child tree can be deleted, can you compute the number of ways the whole tree can be deleted": that exactly is where I am struggling. I think adding/multiplying that for the left and right children would help, but few examples show that is not true.  I just added my analysis.

Comment: No, multiplication is not enough. It also depends on the size of each subtree, or rather the length of the delete sequence. Then you should ask in how many ways can you interleave both delete sequences + root. Because that constructs the delete sequence of the whole tree. Take that number and multiply it by the numbers of ways both subtrees can be deleted. That should be your answer I think.

Comment: @Quimby, how would you define a "delete sequence" in my edited example above?  I tried calculating using the "number of nodes" in each subtree, but that did not help.

Comment: I mean `[2, 4, 3, 1]` as one delete sequence, not sure how to call it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a give node `X`, we want to know `u(X)` - the number of unique delete sequences.

Assume this node has two children `A`, `B` with sizes `|A|`, `|B|` and known `u(A)` and `u(B)`.

How many delete sequences can you construct for `X`? You could take any two sequences from `u(A)` and `u(B)` and root and combine them together. The result will be a valid delete sequence for `X` if the following holds:

- The root `X` must be deleted last.
- Order of deletion of any two nodes from different subtrees is arbitrary.
- Order of deletion of any two nodes from the same subtree is fixed given its chosen delete sequence.

[This means you want to find out the number of ways you can interleave both sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666288/number-of-ways-to-interleave-two-ordered-sequences/666295) (and append `X`).

Notice that the length of a delete sequence is the size of the tree, that's kind of trivial if you think about it.

Also give some though to the fact that this way we can generate all the delete sequences for `X`, that might not be so trivial.

So if I'm counting correctly, the formula you are looking for is `u(X)= [|A|+|B| choose |A|] * u(A) * u(B)`.

It holds for empty children too if we define `u(empty)=1`.

Just be careful about overflow, the number of combinations will explode quite quickly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why "choose |A|" in that equation?

Comment: @Someone No reason at all, the linked answer uses formula `m+n choose m` and combination numbers have the property of `m+n choose m` being equal to `m+n choose n`. So it really does not matter whether you use `A` or `B`.